# Send a terminal command through email

Tags: email, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

Is it possible to send an email which launches a predetermined command on a host machine? I wrote a script that sends an email every time some task finishes and it would be really great if I could send an email back that would launch something else. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: you can execute unix commands using system('mkdir folder') or `mkdir folder`. Not sure if this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not easy but nothing is impossible

Here is an example structure for linux

1. Use alpine to read your mail see [here](http://people.virginia.edu/~ll2bf/docs/nix/alpine.html)
2. Use alpine's notification to run your sendmail script see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1830/how-can-i-customize-new-mail-notification-in-alpine)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is approximately what I was looking for, although it seems to me that I can run only one command, irrespective of the text in the email that I send. I guess it is easier to just ssh and start my scripts remotely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, is the machine receiving the email on the same network? if so you could ssh into the machine automatically and start a process

Comment: The machine that receives the email is on the same network indeed and any time I log in I get a message in the terminal: "New mail" (if there is any). SSH seems better indeed.